# How to run Docker image in GitHub Actions?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, docker-image

I don't want to download the app, I want to run its quay.io image container (that is, by pulling the image from the quay.io hub and running it in GitHub) with this app inside. And then write a couple of commands of this application, the result of which is the goal of the entire job.

What should it look like in GitHub Actions .yaml?

Comment: What have you tried before? Did you make some research or attempt to do it on your own

Comment: I've been searching for a while.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container

```
jobs:
  container-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
       image: ghcr.io/owner/image
```